# instantiation of objects of other classes in java

Tags: java, oop, object

i have this situation:

```
public class Number {
int num;
private TakeNumber take = null;

public Number() {
    num = 5;
}

public void print() {
    take.doSomething();
}

public int getNumber() {
    return num;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Number();
  }
}

public class TakeNumber {
private Number number = new Number();

public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println(number.getNumber());

   }
}
```

Now, can someone explain me these situations:

- I want to know what the compiler interprets here : `private Number number = new Number();`
- Initialize the object in question and passing the required methods
- Is correct initialize one object to null and then call a function on that object, as shown

in brief

I would like to know if you can call a method of a class of another class:

1. without the required function to be static
2. **IMPORTANT** do not inherit the classes because I want to use methods of these classes, for example:

   - **I have classes that are conceptually different as Tomato and machine, I would call the methods of Machine into Tomato**

Comment: There are too many things that you are asking in one question and they are scattered across your question. I would suggest rephrasing and reformatting your question to make it more understandable and get more answers.

Comment: i know, but i wanted to be very clear on my point, making more question for the same concern , will make on me more confsion , i understand the difficult of the answerer.

Comment: At least, collect all the questions that you have at the bottom of your question and make it easier for the answerer to understand what you want to know.

Comment: "Now, can someone explain me why because these situations do not give errors but do not print the number?" - because print() method is not called anywhere in all three situations. If you will call it, you will get NullPointerException because take variable was not initialized.

Comment: i forget to insert in  the main the call of print(), yes, but the main question is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if you can call a method of a class of another class:
>
> without the required function to be static

If the methods are not `static`, then you will need an instance of that object to call it.

```
Object o = new Object();
o.doSomething();
```

Is how you access an instance method.

> I have classes that are conceptually different as Tomato and machine, I would call the methods of Machine into Tomato

This is fine. This is called `composition`. Composition is a `has a` relationship between classes. A class `Man` `has a` class `Car`, but `Is a` class `Person`. And it is perfectly valid to write code as you have shown. This is how you use composition to expose only the interface of a composite object that you want. For example..

```
public class MyClass extends MyOtherClass
```

Now you've just exposed the whole interface of `MyOtherClass`. This might not be desired.

```
public class MyClass {
    MyOtherClass otherClass;

    public void doSomething() {
        otherClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Now, you've only exposed the `doSomething()` method. This is useful when, as you said, your objects are conceptually different, but require some shared functionality. It is a perfectly valid code practise.

***NOTE***: Given the confusing nature of your question, I imagine I've missed some stuff out so please comment with desired edits.

Comment: "Now, you've only exposed the doSomething() method. This is useful when, as you said, your objects are conceptually different, but require some shared functionality. It is a perfectly valid code practise." this sentece open a horizont :D